# Cannot install ruby with asdf on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, openssl, asdf

I encountered an error when installing ruby on my Kubuntu 22.04 using asdf.
When I ran this code
`asdf install ruby 2.6.4`
The terminal show this and stopped forever:

```
Downloading ruby-build...
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /tmp/ruby-build.20230227154534.54979.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/8dee9b24bdb1dcbf0c3d1e9b02fb8f6bf22165e807f45adeb7c9677536859d3b
Installing openssl-1.1.1t...
Installed openssl-1.1.1t to /home/lelouvincx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.4

Downloading ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build 20230222)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20230227154534.54979.cbqQx3
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20230227154534.54979.log

Last 10 log lines:
Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
de0a40|ERR |       0B/s|/tmp/ruby-build.20230227154534.54979.cbqQx3/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2

Status Legend:
(ERR):error occurred.

aria2 will resume download if the transfer is restarted.
If there are any errors, then see the log file. See '-l' option in help/man page for details.
```

Please help!

I tried some different tag with openssl like `ASDF_RUBY_BUILD_VERSION=master asdf install ruby 2.6.4` or `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n asdf install ruby 2.6.4` but not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to these parts:

```
Downloading ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2

...

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
de0a40|ERR |       0B/s|/tmp/ruby-build.20230227154534.54979.cbqQx3/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2

...

aria2 will resume download if the transfer is restarted.
```

The problem is not that Ruby will not compile and that's why the flags you added did not change anything. The problem is that Ruby can't be downloaded at all.

You need to ensure that:

1. The remote host cache.ruby-lang.org is online
2. The remote host cache.ruby-lang.org is reachable from your computer

You can try downloading the file directly with curl:

```bash
curl -O https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2
```

You should see output like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.7M  100 13.7M    0     0   9.9M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  9.9M
```

And you should have the file `ruby-2.6.4.tar.bz2` downloaded as a result. If not then the problem is either 1 or 2 above, and you need to ensure that you are not blocking connections to cache.ruby-lang.org.

Answer (score 1):

Update! I figured it out by this command: `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" asdf install ruby 3.2.0`.

If there's any error, try pre-install these libs: `sudo apt install libyaml-dev libssl-dev`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was trying to install ruby v3.2.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 using asdf. It failed here:
```
❯ asdf install ruby latest
...
-> ./configure "--prefix=$HOME/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2" --enable-shared
-> make -j 12

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20231114)
```
Inspected the logs and found:
```
crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:36:11: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
    36 | # include <zlib.h>
       |           ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```
Running `sudo apt install libyaml-dev libssl-dev` must have added the missing header.